# Multiplication operation using recursion in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I`m new to Python. Now I am learning about recursion. I can't figure out how does this function work.

This function has to multiply two numbers without multiplication operation. It can use only itself(recursion).
And how does this code work if num is not 0? Does it work like cycle until its 0? It works, but I don`t understand how.

```py
a=int(input('Enter a '))
b=int(input('Enter b '))
def mult(a,b):
    if a==0 or b==0:
        return 0
    elif b%2==0:    
        return 2*mult(a, b/2)
    else:
        return mult(a, b-1)+a
print('Result = ', mult(a,b))
```

Comment: Too broad for SO I'm afraid. You'll need to build your intuition around recursion & call stacks. Try a tutorial like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfBqVVKg4GE or ask your teacher, or refer to a textbook.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  "I don't understand" is not a specific problem.  Trace the program execution; print out useful values as it runs.  When you have a *specific* question, *then* you post.

Answer (score 0):

It creates stack like as follows:

```
  mult(4,0) -> return 0;  
  mult(4,1) -> return 4; (0+4)  
  mult(4,2) -> return 8; (2*4)  
  mult(4,4) -> return 16; (2*8)  
  mult(4,5) -> return 20; (16+4)
```

The result of the top stack function call will be returned to the function call below it in the stack. 
  To understand visually view this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kepBmgvWNDw

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to check whether your variable `a` equal to 0 or not. Because it never changed. You always pass the same `a` for any recursion step.

Second, your function will reach state that `b == 0`, because, at each step, you reduce the value of `b` to 1 unit or `b/2` unit. So, it will reach 0.

Comment: `a` may never change, but this is a simple enough way to avoid a full recursive descent to evaluate a call like `mult(0, some_really_big_number)`.

Answer (score 0):

You know a multiplication is a Sumatory of N times of the number itself. Right? So 2 x 4 = 2+2+2+2.

The first parameter takes the base number (a), and the second parameter takes N repetitions (b). What happen when the numbers are different from 0?

If b is greater than 0 means we still having repetitions to sum to the base number (a). So, how we tell we want to sum again? doing the same function **but** we substract 1 repetition to the amount of repetitions (b)

```
mult(a, b-1)
```

Furthermore, we need to sum the next mult to our base number (a), so we sum (a) itself:

```
mult(a, b-1)+a
```

If b is 0, then we finished, because we finished the amount of repetitions.

If a is 0, we didn't even start, cause 0 x N = 0

I don't know what is the second condition, I think is unnecessary.

Comment: The second condition is logically unnecessary, but it makes the implementation more efficient. For those opposed to using `*` in the definition of `mult`, you could rewrite that step as something like `tmp = mult(a, b/2); return tmp + tmp`. (That is, it lets you parenthesize `2 + 2 + 2 + 2` as `(2 + 2) + (2 + 2)` rather than `2 + (2 + (2 + 2))`, and only computes the subsum `2 + 2` once.)

Comment: Why is more efficient? Where can I find info about this?

Comment: It's more efficient because it greatly reduces the number of recursive calls you need to make.

Comment: Superb. I did a test and it's super cool. Didn't know about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a long group of additions (which is all multiplication is):

```
3 * 15 == 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3
```

The naive way to perform this is to add one term at a time.

```
3 * 15 == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 3)))))))))))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 6))))))))))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 9)))))))))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 12))))))))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 15)))))))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 18))))))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 21)))))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 24))))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 27)))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 30))))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + (3 + 33)))
       == 3 + (3 + (3 + 36))
       == 3 + (3 + 39)
       == 3 + 42
       == 45
```

Whew! Fourteen (14) additions. This would correspond to a definition like

```
def mult(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    return a + mult(a, b -1)
```

But there's a better way; if we group the additions differently, we can *reuse* the results of some of our additions.

If we have an even number of values, we divide them into two groups, but only add up *one* of them. Instead of adding up the other group, we just add the result of the first group to itself. If there is an odd number of values, we set aside one, add up the resulting even number of values, then add the odd value back.

```
3 * 15 == 3 + (3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3) + (3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3)
       == 3 + 2 * (3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3)
```

(I've written `2 * t` instead of `t + t` to emphasize that `t` need only be computed once, we'll actually calculate `2 * t` as `t + t` to avoid any explicit multiplication).

We compute the subsequence in the same way.

```
      == 3 + 2 * (3 + (3 + 3 + 3) + (3 + 3 + 3))
      == 3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * (3 + 3 + 3))
```

and again

```
      == 3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * (3 + 0 + 0)))
```

What's that odd `3 + 0 + 0` doing there? It lets us further decompose a "sequence" of only one value as that value plus the sum of two 0-length sequences (because 0 is an even number). A 0-length sequence is trivial to add up: its sum is 0.

Once we are done grouping, it's time to add. Remember, we are computing `2 * t` with `t + t`.

```
      == 3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * (3 + 0)))
      == 3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * 3))
      == 3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * (3 + 6))
      == 3 + 2 * (3 + 2 * 9)
      == 3 + 2 * (3 + 18)
      == 3 + 2 * 21
      == 3 + 42
      == 45
```

That was only 8 additions!

In general, the naive approach to computing `a * b` requires O(b) additions. This recursive approach requires only O(lg b) additions instead.